# Initializing forge-alist

Tags: init-file, magit

I am trying to initialize Magit Forge's `forge-alist` programatically. Therefore I put together my first couple of emacs-lisp code. It looks like the following:

```lisp
(let ((gitlab-install (lambda (host) (list host (concat host "/api/v4") host forge-gitlab-repository))))
  (dolist (host '("gitlab.example.com" "gitlab.foobar.com"))
    (print host)
    (print (funcall gitlab-install host))
    (add-to-list 'forge-alist (funcall gitlab-install host))))
```

Unfortunately it seems that the final `forge-alist` has strange entries even though the `(print)` statement prints out the entries correctly.

```lisp
((#1="gitlab.foobar.com" "gitlab.foobar.com/api/v4" #1# forge-gitlab-repository)
 (#2="gitlab.example.com" "gitlab.example.com/api/v4" #2# forge-gitlab-repository)
  ...)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Sorry for mis-tagging

Comment: No problem. Welcome to emacs.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a list (using `list`) that shares structure. That's what that `#1` syntax tells you.

```lisp
(list host (concat host "/api/v4") host forge-gitlab-repository)
```

You pass, as the value of variable `host`, a string (e.g. `"gitlab.example.com"`).

The anonymous function (lambda) then constructs a list whose first and third elements are each the value you pass it. That is, those elements are **identical** - the same string in this case. They're not copies (separate strings).

This tells you that:

```lisp
(#1="gitlab.foobar.com" "gitlab.foobar.com/api/v4" #1# forge-gitlab-repository)
```

It shows a list whose first element is `"gitlab.foobar.com"`, and which it identifies as the `#1`, and whose third element is shown as `#1#`, which refers to that same element - same string exactly.

If you don't want such shared structure then use `copy-sequence` to get separate strings with the same chars.

But maybe you do want to reuse exactly the same string. Only you can answer that (or perhaps someone acquainted with `gitlab-install`).

Comment: Thank you! The solution was as you recommended to create a copy of the string: `(lambda (host) (list host (concat host "/api/v4") (copy-sequence host) forge-gitlab-repository))`

Comment: The only question left behind in my head is why the originally created list wasn't working with forge.